# How to show out of stock button in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have added a product in opencart with 0 quantity but when I see it in front end then I want to show out of stock text and the add to cart button should also be disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** : It's not recommended to make the direct changes in the core
>   files. You can make the vqmod for the same changes. changes given here
>   are tested in the default template, it might be different in other
>   custom theme.

**Before**
[image]
[image]
**After**

**(1)** Open catalog/controller/product/product.php (approx line num : 273) and search for the line:

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
```

and make the changes as below:

```
$data['stock_qty']=1;
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
    $data['stock_qty']=0;
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
    $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

(2) Open catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl (approx line num 303 to 309)

and wrap the block of **"add to cart button"** inside the condition.

```
<?php if($stock_qty!=0) { ?>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
<br />
<button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the administrative dashboard;

- Hover over the menu bar where it says SYSTEM and then click on
  SETTINGS in the drop-down menu.
- Select the STORE that you wish to edit and then click on EDIT on the 
  far right to proceed.
- Click on the TAB that says OPTION, then scroll down until you see the
  option labeled SHOW OUT-OF-STOCK WARNING.

Comment: If it is out of stock then I want to disable the add to cart button